# Updating data on a previous form

Tags: ms-access

I work for a homeless shelter and am developing a database to track work done by clients at the shelter. The first form shows the number of days the client has remaining (CDays), their work program hours (CWPHours) and their volunteer hours (CVHours), all of which are numbers.

The data from these three are manipulated by a second form when a client turns in a work program credit. Everything seems to work fine, but I cannot get the second form to pass the updated information back to the first form. I keep getting an Error 7878 "The data has been changed". When I step through the code, it works fine,though.

Below is the code for the second form. Sorry if its sloppy, I'm still relatively new at this.

```
Private Sub cmd_Apply_Click()
Dim TempHours As Single
Dim TempDays As Single
Dim TempVol As Single

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

'Update the client work program hours. This starts the chain reaction
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tblClient " & _
    "SET tblClient.CWPHours = [tblClient].[CWPHours]+[Forms]![Work Pay Form]![WPHours] " & _
    "WHERE (((tblClient.ClientID)=[Forms]![Work Pay Form]![ClientID]))"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

'Set temp values based on the current values of the First Form
TempHours = Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![CWPHours]
TempDays = Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![CDays]
TempVol = Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![CVHours]

'Update TempHours to include new credits
TempHours = TempHours + Me.WPHours
TempHours2 = TempHours 'This is used to update TempDays later on

'Convert TempHours of 2 or more into additional days
If TempHours > 1.9 Then
    TempHours = TempHours - (Int(TempHours / 2) * 2)
    TempDays = TempDays + (Int(TempHours2 / 2))
End If

'Convert 10 or more days into volunteer hours
If TempDays > 9.9 Then
    TempVol = TempVol + ((TempDays - 10) * 2)
    TempDays = 10
End If

'Pass the new values back to the First Form
'This is where the problem starts
Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![CWPHours] = TempHours
Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![CDays] = TempDays
Forms![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform].Form![CVHours] = TempVol
DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

The three lines at the end are the ones causing the issue. If anybody has any suggestions, i appreciate your help.

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually unnecessary and bad design. It should be calculated based on raw data records when needed.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the math to calculate it.